# Match exact string against an array / list - Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

The `service_name` variable prints the following.

```
"msg": [
    "BLAH PEX",
    "BLAH AEX non prod",
    "BLAH BIND",
    "BLAH DBFactory"
]
```

I want to match the variable `BSA` which contains the string `BLAH BIND`. I tried something like this:

```
- debug:
    msg: "Match found"
  when: "BSA in service_name"
```

It works! But the problem is, it also matches if the `BSA` contains the string `BLAH`. I want it to only match if there is a exact match. Right now its matching word by word I guess.

Expected Output: It should skip the debug task because when `BSA` contains the string `BLAH`, it should not match any strings in the `service_name` list.

Any help how to achieve to match the entire exact string in the array.

I am using ansible 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: *"Expected Output: It should skip the debug task because when BSA contains the string BLAH, it should not match any strings in the service_name list."*

A: It's working as expected. String "BLAH" doesn't match and the debug task is skipped.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    service_name: [ "BLAH PEX", "BLAH AEX non prod", "BLAH BIND", "BLAH DBFactory" ]
    BSA: "BLAH"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: service_name
    - debug:
        var: BSA
    - debug:
        msg: "Match found"
      when: "BSA in service_name"
    - debug:
        msg: "Continue"
```

gives

```
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml

PLAY [localhost] ***

TASK [debug] ***
ok: [localhost] => {
    "service_name": [
        "BLAH PEX", 
        "BLAH AEX non prod", 
        "BLAH BIND", 
        "BLAH DBFactory"
    ]
}

TASK [debug] ***
ok: [localhost] => {
    "BSA": "BLAH"
}

TASK [debug] ***
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Continue"
}

PLAY RECAP ***
localhost: ok=3  changed=0  unreachable=0  failed=0  skipped=1  rescued=0  ignored=0
```

Comment: thanks @Vlamdimir. It works as expected, I confused myself.

Comment: I find it interesting that string BSA does not need to be wrapped in single quotes (e.g. 'BSA' in service_name) or double quotes (e.g. "BSA" in service_name) to be interpreted as a string. Great piece of intel here.

Comment: As of the quoting. 1) See [Examples of debug](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html#examples). [var](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html#parameter-var) needs `the name of a variable` and [msg](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html#parameter-msg) needs `the message`. 2) See [How to use variable substitution in a when condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65866313/how-to-use-variable-substitution-in-a-when-condition). Thank you for comment.